# BadTokenException even if I check if Activity isFinishing()

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, crash

I have the following code in my `Activity` to show a warning `Dialog` if an error occurred:

```
private void showConfigError() {
        if (!isFinishing()) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setMessage(R.string.start_failed)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton(*/.../*)
                    .setNegativeButton(*/.../*)
                    .create()
                    .show();
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I check if the `Activity` is still running, before I show the `Dialog`. But nevertheless my crashlog show that sometimes a `BadTokenException` happens in this part of the program. Now I am asking myself how this can happen?! Is there a state where the `Activity` can return `isFinishing() == false` but is not active anymore?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
    private void showConfigError() {
    if (isFinishing()) return; 

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage(R.string.start_failed)
                .setCancelable(true)        // let system kills it.
                .setPositiveButton(*/.../*)
                .setNegativeButton(*/.../*)
                .create()
                .show();

   }
```

Comment: What is the difference between doing nothing and just 'return' ?

Comment: these is chance that activity may be get killed after the isFinishing() check and system try to dismiss dialog but you made it setCancelable(false)

Comment: But unfortunately this Dialog requires to be not cancelable